# Calculus II: 3d graph question

Tags: calculus

The graph of $z = f (x, y)$  is shown below. In each part, determine whether the given partial derivatives are positive, negative, or zero. (Note that the function is symmetric about 0 in both the x- and y- directions.)
Graph for Problem #2
[image]

(a)      $f_x(2, −2)$   and   $f_{xx}(2, −2)$

(b)      $f_y(2, −2)$   and   $f_{yy}(2, −2)$

(c)      $f_x(−2, 0)$   and   $f_{xx}(−2, 0)$

(d)      $f_y(−2, 0)$   and    $f_{yy}(−2, 0)$

I have no idea how to solve this question. I am so sorry to just ask like this but our math teacher just went over this topic very briefly and I couldn't find an example question similar to this.

Comment: You need equation of curve. We can't find from graph!

Comment: This is all the question gives. I was expecting an equation too ??

Comment: This might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dfvnCHqzK54&list=PLSQl0a2vh4HC5feHa6Rc5c0wbRTx56nF7&index=16

Comment: You don't need the equation for the surface. For example, find the point on the surface corresponding to $(2,-2)$. Is the slope along the $x$ direction positive, negative or zero? What about the convexity?

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit further? For example there are two different (2,-2) for partial derivative respect to x and partial derivative respect to y. How can I evaluate these two?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

- The graph looks like $z=y^2-x^2$.
- For example for $f_{\color{green}{x}}(\color{green}{2},\color{blue}{-2})$ you imagine a plane parallel to the $\color{green}{x}z$-plane which is positioned at $\color{blue}{y=-2}$.
- This plane intersects with the graph and cuts off the curve $z = \color{blue}{(-2)^2}-x^2 = 4-x^2$.
- Now, check slope and convexity of the graph of $z= 4-x^2$ at $\color{green}{x = 2}$.
- Be careful while using **your** picture as the $x$-axis is **reversely scaled**.

[image]